# JPanel Exact drawing size/Limit?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

When drawing on my extended `JPanel` I want the size to be variable. I've worked out the code to always outline a 1 pixel margin. My code works but I don't understand why I must adjust the height and width and height of the dimension by -1 when drawing the rectangle.

If I draw a rectangle that has `1,1` as a size it draws a single pixel square so shouldn't drawing the width and the height work without the -1 modifier.

If any one can explain why there is a discrepancy between the size of my extended `JPanel` or explain a better way to get the exact dimensions of the drawing area I would appreciate it.

```
public class Engine extends JPanel {
  Engine(){
  }
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Dimension a = this.getSize();
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, a.width-1, a.height-1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, most values are 0 based. But instead of having to say, " I want the width of my panel to be 199" so you get a panel that is 200 pixels wide (0-199), Swing allows you to specify 1 based values and makes adjustments internally

If you create a rectangle of 1, 1, 1, 1, your actually creating a rectangle at position 1x1, whose width & height is 1 pixel (1 + 1 would be 2)

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped me, it makes sense that this.getSize would return a value that starts counting at one not zero. It still confuses me how the rectangle draws one pixel farther then I want it to.

Comment: Some testing does show it seems to add to from the starting pixel, even if it starts at (0,0).

Answer (score 1):

> "or explain a better way to get the exact dimensions of the drawing area I would appreciate it."

Override `getPreferredSize()` in your `JPanel` class

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(300, 300);
}
```

When you you paint, make use of `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, inherited from the `JPanel` class. Using these methods, your painting will resize dynamically with the resizing of the panel.

```
int width = getWidth();
int height = getHeight();
g.fillRect((int)(width * 0.9), (int)(height * 0.9), 
           (int)(width * 0.8), (int)(height * 0.8));
```

---

**Side Note**

- You should call `super.paintComponent` inside the `paintComponent` method so as not to break the paint chain.
- `paintComponent` should be `protected` not `public`

  ```
  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

  }
  ```

Comment: When you override a method, you can loosen the access.  You can make paintComponent public, although there's not a good reason for doing so with the paintComponent method.

Comment: Thank you, I was using public because my IDE warned me I couldn't use private. I hadn't realized I was relaxing protections. Also getWidth() and getHeight() is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

> I've worked out the code to always outline a 1 pixel margin.

Don't do custom painting. Use a `Swing Border`. See [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html). You probably want a `LineBorder`.

Comment: You are right I should not be drawing a border myself. I must admit though that I posted this problem because I'm don't want to draw out of bounds.